# Multi Image upload with Grocery CRUD and Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, image-uploading, grocery-crud

I Have two table named products and product_images. I want to upload multiple image for a particular product. My table structure are below

products :

p_id

name

.....

product_images :

img_id

name

url

p_id

is there any way to do it with Grocery CRUD ???

Comment: You are missing something.Can you further elaborate?At the moment your table structure is fine and you can also upload multiple images.